# Android manifest merge - Different launcher activity from library project

Tags: android, merge, android-manifest

I have a library project which has the following structure :

```
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A1">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A3">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A4">
    </activity>
```

In the app project I want the merged manifest to be :

```
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A1">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A3">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A4">
    </activity>
```

Is it possible to achieve this using manifest merger feature?

If I try to have

```
    <activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

in the base manifest file of the app project, I am getting the following error.

```
  Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.comp.package.activities.A2] element:
  <activity
      @android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
  --    <intent-filter>
  --        <action
  --            @android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
   <activity
      @android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
  ++</activity>
  ++(end reached)
```

Answer (score 10):

Change the AndroidManifest in the consuming app/lib from:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
...
<activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2">
```

To:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
...
<activity android:name="com.comp.package.activities.A2"
    tools:merge="override">
```

Comment: This solution bitrotted. See a working one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239844/gradle-merge-wrapper-sub-modules-android-manifest-into-a-main-modules-manifest

Comment: @Oded true dat! Changed to `tools:replace="android:name"`