# Gradle merge wrapper/sub-module's Android manifest into a main module's manifest

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following modules inside my project for which I cannot get Gradle to merge the Android manifests properly:

```
myproject_alpha
myproject_beta
myproject_lib
myproject_release
```

The *_lib module is the main module for the project that contains all source code. The other 3 modules are "wrapper modules" that make slight modifications to the content providers' "authorities" parameter, change the "data" field inside an activity's intent filter specified in the *_lib module's manifest, plus enable some other activities not present in myproject_release module.

Currently, I have gradle Android manifest merging errors between alpha (or beta or release) vs lib. For example, between lib and alpha I see the following 2 gradle errors:

```
Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/provider[@name=com.myproject.contentprovider.MyProvider] element:
  <provider
--    @android:authorities="com.myproject.alpha.provider"
  <provider
++    @android:authorities="com.myproject.lib.provider"

:myproject_alpha:processDebugManifest FAILED

Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=com.myproject.activity.LoginActivity] element:
  <activity
  @android:name="com.myproject.activity.LoginActivity"
          @android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
  <intent-filter>
          @android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
      <data
--            @android:host="myhost.test.com"
  <activity
  @android:name="com.myproject.LoginActivity"
          @android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER">
  <intent-filter>
          @android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE">
          @android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
      <data
++            @android:host="myhost.com"

:myproject_alpha:processDebugManifest FAILED
```

The only similar question I found was
[Gradle: How to merge Android manifest files for different buildTypes which need the same Activity, but with different intent-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18708076/gradle-how-to-merge-android-manifest-files-for-different-buildtypes-which-need). However, it doesn't really match my issue because in my case "lib" and "alpha" are interdependent modules not different builds. I'll appreciate some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you examine the [class that merges the manifests](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/manifest-merger/src/main/java/com/android/manifmerger/ManifestMerger.java), you'll see that the `mergeNewOrEqual()` method is not smart enough to merge elements that are not identical. Unfortunately, this is the method that is used to merge providers and activities.

So the only "solution" would be to either to only define the elements in one place, or to give them identical signatures in both definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, it was useful. We inherited the code from an outside team, so not sure if they ever got the code to build as it is. For now I edited all manifests to use the same signatures and on a future release I'll restructure the codebase to make better use of gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I have issues with the answer above in that when I compile, I always get the message

> Invalid instruction 'merge', valid instructions are :
>   REMOVE,REPLACE,STRICT

I found success in importing the tools as in @swooby answer and then adding `tools:node="merge"` in the `<activity>` tag for the Activity being launched I want to replace and then adding

```
<intent-filter tools:node="remove">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
```

to the Activity's launcher that I do not want to have a launcher icon

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the update. The previous solution must have bit rotted. I verified that this works as I expect in both product flavors that I'm using it for, by inspecting the generated intermediate manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the header of your manifest as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

Then, use one of the following appropriate attributes on any activity, activity-alias, service, receiver, or provider element that you want to merge:

```
tools:merge="override"
tools:merge="remove"
```

This info was gleaned from:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/idea133/build-system/manifest-merger/src/main/java/com/android/manifmerger/ManifestMerger.java

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work".  What does the merged manifest look like? Please provide a copy of the sub-manifest and the super-manifest.

Comment: It will say: Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/activity[@name=#provider#] element:

Comment: What type of element are you trying to merge? Please provide a snippet of your manifests.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work:     
  <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
            tools:merge="override"
            >
I want to merge android:uiOptions ,bug failed